# Find filename extension in directory

Tags: c++, parsing, directory, filenames

All,

I'm new to C++, so I may not be searching for the right function, terminology, etc. I'm using getopt to get arguments on the command line. Those arguments are directories on the local drive. When the code is executed, I want it to look in that directory for a certain file extension. When it finds the extension, I'll do something with the file, rename the file, and then copy the file to another location. I'm stuck on just trying to find the filename extension. I've gotten as far as showing all files in the directories:

main.cpp:

```
int opt = 0;

/* If the argument count passes, check for all arguments */

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "b:m:o:Hh")) != EOF) {
    switch(opt) {
        case 'b':
            dirCopyEvent(optarg);
            break;
```

dirCopyEvent.cpp:

```
void dirCopyEvent(char *fileToFind) {
cout << "You chose the directory " << fileToFind << endl;

DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
char *extension;
extension = strchr(dir->d_name, '.txt');

d = opendir(fileToFind);

if (d != NULL) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d))) {
         cout << "Filename is " << dir -> d_name << endl;
}
```

The dirCopyEvent is called from main. I know I need to parse d_name for a filename and then find the extension somehow, but that's where I'm lost. Any help is greatly appreciated!

- Edit *
  Just to add an example:

I have a directory called Test. In that directory, I have 3 files: test1.txt anothertest.txt yetanothertest.bat

I want to ONLY be able to show a result of test1.txt and anothertest.txt, but not yetanothertest.bat. When I find the txt extension in the name, I want to be able to pass it to another function to do something with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need something like strrchr function, however it not the C++ way. This is how it goes:

```
char *ext = strrchr(dir->d_name,'.'); //extension, including the dot
```

note, that

- ext will be `NULL` if there is no dot in the filename.
- you must include `<string.h>` or `<cstring>`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is find the last occurrence of the dot in the string like below.

```
char *extension;
extension = strrchr(dir->d_name, '.');
```

Comment: I put this in my code (edited above), but how to I now validate that the extension is in fact in the directory?

Comment: Traverse through all the files in the directory and apply the strchr on whatever extension type you want. If the return type is null, the character searched is not there in the filename. Also, strchr will search a character(not a string) and from beginning of the string. strrchr will search from end. You need to search from end for extension as there can be "dot" in a filename also.  check this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strrchr/